# How to Return a List of Values From Within a Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to return a list of values for a given id number using two previously created dictionaries, where the values I need are stored within the dictionaries.

The two dictionaries I've created are as follows:

```
{100: ('Mulan', [300, 500], [200, 400]), 
200: ('Ariel', [100, 500], [500]), 
300: ('Jasmine', [500], [500, 100]), 
400: ('Elsa', [100, 500], []), 
500: ('Belle', [200, 300], [100, 200, 300, 400])}

{100000: (400, 'Does not want to build a %SnowMan %StopAsking', ['SnowMan', 'StopAsking'], [100, 200, 300], [400, 500]), 
100001: (200, 'Make the ocean great again.', [''], [], [400]), 
100002: (500, "Help I'm being held captive by a beast!  %OhNoes", ['OhNoes'], [400], [100, 200, 300]), 
100003: (500, "Actually nm. This isn't so bad lolz :P %StockholmeSyndrome", ['StockholmeSyndrome'], [400, 100], []), 
100004: (300, 'If some random dude offers to %ShowYouTheWorld do yourself a favour and %JustSayNo.', ['ShowYouTheWorld', 'JustSayNo'], [500, 200], [400]), 
100005: (400, 'LOLZ BELLE.  %StockholmeSyndrome  %SnowMan', ['StockholmeSyndrome', 'SnowMan'], [], [200, 300, 100, 500])}
```

The first dictionary is of the form {id: (name, followers, following}.

The second dictionary is of the form {key: (id, chirp,  tags, likes, dislikes}.

For the given id numbers `100, 200, 300, 400, 500`, I need to return the chirp with the most likes for each user they follow.

An example of the output, for say id number 500, would be:

```
['Make the ocean great again.', 
'If some random dude offers to %ShowYouTheWorld do yourself a favour and %JustSayNo.', 
'Does not want to build a %SnowMan %StopAsking']
```

I understand the process that needs to happen here, but I need some help with how to get the function to find the necessary value in one dictionary, and then search for the required values in the second dictionary.

Thanks so much for any guidance you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use nested loops to go through both dictionaries starting with the first:

```
user_input = 500

for key, value in dictionary1.items():
if user_input == key:
    for key2, value2 in dictionary2.items():
        for items in value[1]:  
            if items == value2[0]:
                print(value2[1])
```

key = id

value[1][0] = name

value[1][1] = followers

value[1][2] = following

key2 = key

value2[0] = id

value2[1] = chirp

value2[2] = tags

value2[3] = likes

value2[4] = dislikes

Comment: What about when the user follows multiple people? I.e, if we set 'user_input = 500', we should get back the three chirps, one each from user 200, 300, 400. However, when i run this code, it only returns '['If some random dude offers to %ShowYouTheWorld do yourself a favour and %JustSayNo.']', as opposed to '['Make the ocean great again.', 
'If some random dude offers to %ShowYouTheWorld do yourself a favour and %JustSayNo.', 
'Does not want to build a %SnowMan %StopAsking']'. Would you know how to solve this issue? Thanks again!!

Comment: @JakeThompson I was responding to "I understand the process that needs to happen here, but I need some help with how to get the function to find the necessary value in one dictionary, and then search for the required values in the second dictionary." 
I was able to provide you the indexes of each of the values you'll need. It would only take a little bit more logic to get the last line. Once you figure that out, you'll earn some exp and level up.